# Проблема при создании своего элемента управления WinFroms

Tags: c#, winforms

Объясните в чем проблема: 
делаю вот так:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp_MultiplicationTable
{
    public class MyButton : Button
    {
        public int Index { get; set; }
    }
}
```

В элементах управления появляется MyButton, но как только я на него нажимаю и хочу перенести его на форму, то вот что я вижу:

```
Не удалось загрузить элемент "MyButton1" панели элементов. Он будет удален из панели инструментов.
```

Где-то прочитал, что мб проблемы из-за сборки под разные CPU, но у меня нет таких несовпадений.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, тем, кто столкнется с данной проблемой, за решением сюда - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/77e10b58-43cc-4aab-919f-888f14f99571/x64-class-library-of-user-controls?forum=csharpgeneral

Также нужно добавить пустой конструктор экземпляра.